# Dynamically get all parameter values in stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

Is there any way to get all parameter values from a stored procedure dynamically?

In other words, iterate through all parameters in one stored procedure to get their values into one string. This is for a unified logging process for a bunch of stored procedures.

I can get the names of parameters:

```
SELECT PARAMETER_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETER
WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME = 'procedure_name';
```

Also, I tried to use dynamic SQL commands. I've generated a command with included parameter, but EXEC can't execute command.

```
@cmd = 'SELECT '@UserID' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @UserID) 
             + '@Date' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @Date)'
EXEC @cmd
```

Is there any way to do this besides manually generating a list of parameter values for each stored procedure?

Comment: Even for logging, the person writing the stored procedure needs to add the code for logging anyway.

Comment: Stored procedures have written already, I'm looking way for easy implementation. In best case, some dynnmically piece of code that will work in all SP without of metter how many parameters does it has.

Comment: So what is your problem really?

Comment: @Rafael To write universal code for this. Like way to get parameters name in post.

Comment: you mean from inside the stored procedure's code? so you could like paste a "logging code" snipped into every existing procedure and have the call logged along with the values of any parameters that proc might have or not have? cute idea. I did that once without the parameters (just logging which procs have been called and how often, for code coverage testing). is that what you want? recherche: [here](http://sqlity.net/en/976/capturing-parameters-of-a-stored-procedure-call/) and [here](http://sqlity.net/en/976/capturing-parameters-of-a-stored-procedure-call)

Comment: @dlatikay Yes, this is exactly what I want. I've read that article, but I'm not sure can I implement something like that. The first screenshot in article is from which app?

Comment: screenshot is from SQL Management Studio > Tools > SQL Server Profiler > Trace Properties > Event Selection.

Comment: this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595952/dynamically-retrieve-parameter-names-current-values-inside-t-sql-stored-proced contains a partial solution of this problem. It uses cached query plan data from within the executing procedure. if we found a way to invalidate the query plan cache every time, it might actually do the job - with a performance penalty.

Answer (score 3):

Since SQL Server 2014 there is `sys.dm_exec_input_buffer` a table valued function with an output column `event_info` that gives the full execution statement (including parameters).

I use this for error logging in stored procedures.

For example:

```
--include this inside the stored procedure
declare @statement nvarchar(max)
select  @statement = event_info 
from    sys.dm_exec_input_buffer(@@spid, current_request_id())

--this will print whatever you called the procedure with (including parameters)
print @statement

-- if you want to parse just the parameters from the statement, it can be done like this
declare @proc_name varchar(128) = object_name(@@procid)
declare @param_idx int = charindex(@proc_name, @statement) + len(@proc_name)
declare @param_len int = len(@statement) - @param_idx 
declare @params nvarchar(max) = right(@statement, @param_len)

select  @params
```