# SQL stored procedure get dynamic parameter list with values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic, parameters

I have an interesting scenario where I need to get a dynamic list of parameter values from inside a stored procedure.  I want a generic t-sql script that will return this information to me without having to type out each parameter name.

The reason for this is that before executing multiple stored procedures, I must first pass the list of parameter values into another stored procedure call. I don't want the tedious maintenance task that whenever a parameter is added/changed in the SP, I will have to change the nested call as well.

Ex:

```
create procedure sp1 @a int = 1, @b int = 2
as begin

exec sp2 '1, 2'

....

end
```

Adding another parameter `@c int`, should automatically get added on to the string passed in to sp2.

I know I can retrieve the parameter names from `sys.parameters` using `object_id = @@procid`.  I can concatenate them using `for xml path`.  However, I would need to then use `sp_executesql` to retreive the values - which would require me to specify each parameter name. Hence, I am no better off than before.

Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are your parameters changing so frequently? You going to have to use dynamic sql here and very likely a string splitter or a table valued parameter. This has a lot of indicators of a less than optimal design to me.

Comment: I have a number of procedures where this code snippet will be going and for consistency purposes, I would like the code to be generic and identical in all places.

Comment: The only way to dynamically generate something like this is with dynamic sql. You would have to build your calls to sub-procedures with dynamic sql. I suspect you would spend as much or more time creating the logic for this as it will take to just update the procedure calls. The problem with t-sql is that it can't be generic and dynamic when it comes to parameters and columns. It is a declarative language not procedural like a programming language.

Comment: @SeanLange doesn't need to be dynamic, I use something like for this error logging  the parameter values in catch blocks, [here's another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56660221/1062992). Gonna vote to dup close this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically Retrieve Parameter Names & Current Values Inside T-SQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595952/dynamically-retrieve-parameter-names-current-values-inside-t-sql-stored-proced)