# Is there is a way to track the record of stored Procedure running on Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is Sql server provides us any tool to track the executed procedure with their paramter.. I know this can be done by looking at our server side logic before we call the procedure. But I still want to know if tool exsist or not. If yes then How can do this.

Comment: see my answer here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595952/dynamically-retrieve-parameter-names-current-values-inside-t-sql-stored-proced/30598253#30598253

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SQL Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx).

If the stored procedure is called directly from your app, you can use the [RPC:starting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175927.aspx) event. Otherwise you may try to trace the [sp:starting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191287.aspx) event.

For more info check here:

http://sqlity.net/en/976/capturing-parameters-of-a-stored-procedure-call/

> So both events do not cover all cases. If you are trying to see all
>   calls to a procedure from an application, go with [RPC:starting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175927.aspx). If on
>   the other hand the procedure gets executed as part of a bigger batch
>   or from within another procedure, use [sp:starting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191287.aspx) but be aware
>   that variable usage might hide the actual parameter values from you.

Comment: Is there any setting in Sql server, by which we can access the execution time... without any code.

Comment: @lipikachakraborty There is the Duration column in SQL Profiler - https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/how-to-identify-slow-running-queries-with-sql-profiler/

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a custom Data Collector if you have Management Data Warehouse setup on your server. You can also use a DMV to track this, sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats. If you use the dmv, setup a table to store the data, and then dump the dmv data at regular intervals to your table.

Comment: I try to find out the exact command or procedure called with output time ,how can I find this in table. Plz explain